# Slow SQL query when upgrading to COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL 120

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, compatibility-level

We have been running our databases in COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL < 120 for a while now since we can't pinpoint why some queries run really slow.
Not I feel like it's a perfect cure for the covid-19 boredom to fix this and hence I try to tackle the problems the new (ehh... not so new anymore) CE.

So, I've got a fairly simple query involving 3 tables and 2 Table value parameters

```
declare @spIDs as table (id int not null primary key);
INSERT INTO @spIDs values(1),(2); -- 169 in my sql script

DECLARE @subscriptionProductGroupMapping AS table
( 
    subscriptionProductID int not null,
    groupID int not null,
    primary key(subscriptionProductID, groupID)
);
INSERT INTO @subscriptionProductGroupMapping (subscriptionProductID, groupID) 
VALUES(101,101); -- 168 in my script

SELECT
    [dbo].[User].[userID]
FROM
    [dbo].[User]
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT [UserValidThrough].userID 
        FROM 
            [dbo].[UserValidThrough] 
            INNER JOIN @spIDs spIDs on(spIDs.id = [dbo].[UserValidThrough].subscriptionProductID)
    ) AS [uvt] ON [uvt].[userID] = [User].userID
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT userID
        FROM 
        GroupMembership
        INNER JOIN
        @subscriptionProductGroupMapping as SPIAndGroup ON(GroupMembership.groupID = SPIAndGroup.groupID)
    ) gms ON(gms.userID = [User].userID) 
WHERE
    [User].permissionType NOT IN(8, 16, 32, 64, 128) AND
    [User].deleteDate IS NULL AND
    [User].userTypeID IN(@userTypeID_0) AND
    [uvt].[userID] IS NULL
```

When running this query with compatibility level 110 the query is lightning fast, less than 0.3 seconds. 
When changing to compatibility level 120 the query takes about 8-9 seconds to execute! :(

When investigating the actual execution plan I see that there is one clustered index seek that's allocating about 7 seconds, hence I focus on that part

[image: Actual execution plan]
[image: Explanation of slow clustered Index seek]

I've tried to break out this query into another Table value parameter and then the query is fast again. This would however imply that I have to rewrite my application on many places and I'd really like to know why this is slow and what to do about it.

Can anyone shed some light over this problem?

Edit 2020-04-15 12:57 CET
This is a debug script that reproduces a simplified scenario:
1. Create debug tables and debug data

```
create table temp_User 
(
    userID int not null,
    -- Additional columns ommited for readability
    primary key (useriD)
);

create table temp_UserValidThrough 
(
    userID int not null,
    subscriptionProductID int not null,
    -- Additional columns ommited for readability
    primary key(userID, subscriptionProductID)
);

create table temp_GroupMembership
(
    userID int not null,
    groupID int not null,
    primary key(userID, groupID)
);


CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX temp_GroupMembership_GroupIDWithUserID 
ON [dbo].[temp_GroupMembership] ([groupID])
INCLUDE ([userID])

-- populate User
-- populate UserValidThrough
-- populate GroupMembership
declare @noUsers as int = 120000;
declare @noGroups as int = 400;

SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @n as int = 0;
while @n < @noUsers
begin
    insert into temp_User values(@n);

    declare @rand as int = rand() * @noGroups;
    insert into temp_UserValidThrough VALUES(@n, @rand);
    insert into temp_GroupMembership VALUES(@n, @rand); 

    SET @n = @n + 1;
end;
```

2. This query can be executed with different COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL settings and the performance will differ much.

```
DECLARE @userTypeID_0 AS Int;
SET @userTypeID_0 = '1';

declare @spIDs as table (id int not null primary key);
insert into @spIDs
select distinct groupID from temp_GroupMembership;

DECLARE @subscriptionProductGroupMapping AS table
( 
    subscriptionProductID int not null,
    groupID int not null,
    primary key(subscriptionProductID, groupID)
);
insert into @subscriptionProductGroupMapping
SELECT
    T.groupID as subscriptionProductID,
    T.groupID
FROM
    (select distinct groupID from temp_GroupMembership) AS T;


SELECT
    [User].[userID]
FROM
    [dbo].[temp_User] AS [User]
    --LEFT JOIN
    --(
    --  SELECT DISTINCT [UserValidThrough].userID 
    --  FROM 
    --      [dbo].[UserValidThrough] 
    --      INNER JOIN @spIDs spIDs on(spIDs.id = [dbo].[UserValidThrough].subscriptionProductID)
    --) AS [uvt] ON [uvt].[userID] = [User].userID
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT userID
        FROM 
        temp_GroupMembership as GroupMembership
        INNER JOIN
        @subscriptionProductGroupMapping as SPIAndGroup ON(GroupMembership.groupID = SPIAndGroup.groupID)
    ) gms ON(gms.userID = [User].userID) 
WHERE
    --[User].permissionType NOT IN(8, 16, 32, 64, 128) AND
    --[User].deleteDate IS NULL AND
    --[User].userTypeID IN(@userTypeID_0) AND
    NOT EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT [UserValidThrough].userID 
        FROM 
            [dbo].[UserValidThrough] 
            --INNER JOIN @spIDs spIDs on(spIDs.id = [dbo].[UserValidThrough].subscriptionProductID)
        WHERE
            [UserValidThrough].userID = [User].userID
            AND
            [UserValidThrough].subscriptionProductID IN(SELECT id from @spIDs)
    )
    --[uvt].[userID] IS NULL 

declare @lvl as varchar (10) = (SELECT compatibility_level FROM sys.databases WHERE name = DB_NAME());

print 'COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL: ' + @lvl
-- COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL 110 time: average 242 ms
-- COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL 120 time: average 40 s! (200 times slower!)
```

Comment: instead of `LEFT JOIN() AS uvt..WHERE [uvt].[userID] IS NULL`  try  `NOT EXISTS(... where [UserValidThrough].userID = [User].userID)`

Comment: Note the row count estimates for TVPs is 1. Try adding an `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` query hint to the `SELECT` query.

Comment: @DanGuzman: The OPTION(RECOMPILE) makes the query go fast again. Now it's like average 377 ms on 10 tries. That's awesome!
The question now is when should this be used? We have many queries like this in the application and if doesn't feel very good to include OPTION(RECOMPILE) to all of them. :/

Comment: @SwedenDrew, the option should be used judiciously (e.g. not for complex queries that are run many times a second) but can be appropriate for problem queries when the runtime costs with a suboptimal plan exceed the cost of compilation each time. Note the default TVP row count estimate is 100 rather than 1 in newer SQL versions and Azure SQL Database. I suggest you introduce hints only when you observe a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #spIDs 
(
    id int not null primary key
);

CREATE TABLE #subscriptionProductGroupMapping
( 
    subscriptionProductID int not null,
    groupID int not null,
    primary key(subscriptionProductID, groupID)
);

CREATE TABLE #Users
(
    UserID int not null primary key
);

INSERT INTO #subscriptionProductGroupMapping (subscriptionProductID, groupID) 
VALUES(101,101); -- 168 in my script

INSERT INTO #spIDs values(1),(2); -- 169 in my sql script

INSERT INTO #Users (UserID)
SELECT DISTINCT userID
FROM GroupMembership
INNER JOIN #subscriptionProductGroupMapping as SPIAndGroup
    ON(GroupMembership.groupID = SPIAndGroup.groupID)

SELECT
    [dbo].[User].[userID]
FROM
    [dbo].[User]
    INNER JOIN #Users gms 
        ON gms.userID = [User].userID
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT [UserValidThrough].userID 
        FROM [dbo].[UserValidThrough] 
        INNER JOIN #spIDs spIDs 
            on spIDs.id = [dbo].[UserValidThrough].subscriptionProductID
    ) AS [uvt] ON [uvt].[userID] = [User].userID
WHERE
    [User].permissionType NOT IN(8, 16, 32, 64, 128) AND
    [User].deleteDate IS NULL AND
    [User].userTypeID IN(@userTypeID_0) AND
    [uvt].[userID] IS NULL
```

Comment: Yes, that went fast. The problem is however that we're using the TVP's as arguments from the application. I could probably fill the temporary table with the data from the TVP however. This isn't the fancy solution i was hoping for however. :( 
Isn't there some way of giving the optimizer hints of how to handle the query?

Comment: What's TVP? The code can be used in stored procedure.

Comment: Sorry, TVP = Table valued parameter

Comment: Well, what's the issue to wrap this code in stored procedure - it can have TVP as well.